# RenderListDataAsStream REST API endpoint support in SP2013 On-Prem?

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Is the RenderListDataAsStream REST API endpoint supported in SharePoint 2013 On-Prem?  When using POSTMAN to craft a POST REST query, I'm getting a 'NotFound' return.